# Replace multiple strings in one column with other values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column with dozens of different strings, but there are a handful that need to be changed while all the rest maintain the same. As a reproducible example I have the following:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE)
x
tibble(x) %>% dplyr::mutate(x, x = case_when(x=="a"~"Apple",
                                           x=="c"~"Cat"))
```

The expected output is

```
     x    
   <chr>
 1 Cat  
 2 Cat  
 3 Apple
 4 Cat  
 5 b   
 6 b   
 7 Cat  
 8 Apple
 9 b   
10 Cat
```

but I get

```
     x    
   <chr>
 1 Cat  
 2 Cat  
 3 Apple
 4 Cat  
 5 NA   
 6 NA   
 7 Cat  
 8 Apple
 9 NA   
10 Cat
```

How do I avoid `NA`s when I want the original string if I did not specify a new string in place of the old string?

Comment: Try `mutate(x, x = case_when(x=="a"~"Apple",
                                             x=="c"~"Cat",
                                             TRUE ~ x))`

Comment: That did it. Go ahead at submit as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to `dpyr`, you could try using `ifelse` within `ifelse`

```
ifelse(x == "a","Apple",ifelse(x == "c", "cat", x))

[1] "cat" "cat"  "Apple" "cat" "b"  "b" "cat"  "Apple" "b"  "cat"
```

Answer (score 0):

The most exact answer for the question given was provided in the comments by AntoniosK as follows:

```
mutate(x, x = case_when(x=="a"~"Apple", x=="c"~"Cat", TRUE ~ x))
```

Which will keep all remaining values as they are. It is crucial that `TRUE ~ x` be the last argument in `case_when()` as it will match all cases and therefore any following cases will not be checked.